# AWS Cloudformation:Template validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I am using the below template to create a job definition using the cloudformation. When I upload this template, I am getting the error:

"Template validation error: Invalid template property or properties [JobDefinition]"

did I miss something in my template?

```
{
  "JobDefinition": {
    "Type": "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition",
    "Properties": {
      "Type": "container",
      "JobDefinitionName" : "filedownload",
      "ContainerProperties": {
        "Image": "abc",
        "Vcpus": 4,
        "Memory": 2000,
        "JobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/batchjobRole",
        "ReadonlyRootFilesystem": true,
        "Privileged": true
    },   
    "RetryStrategy" : {"attempts": 1}    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that your 'complete' template?

Comment: yes,I am trying to create a batchjob defiintion using this template

Comment: Do i have to specify all the parameters for job definition eventhough i am not using them ?

Comment: No. See this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-batch-jobdefinition.html for which fields are mandatory.

Comment: @nadish Is your template indented properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `"JobDefinition"` inside `"Resources"`. For example:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "JobDefinition": {
      "Type": "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "container",
        "JobDefinitionName" : "filedownload",
        "ContainerProperties": {
          "Image": "abc",
          "Vcpus": 4,
          "Memory": 2000,
          "JobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/batchjobRole",
          "ReadonlyRootFilesystem": true,
          "Privileged": true
      },   
      "RetryStrategy" : {"attempts": 1}    
      }
    }
  }
}
```